# Binary variable constraint

Tags: linear-programming, modeling, constraint-programming, binary-variable, logical-constraints

The task is to ensure that if $x_i = 1$ for at least $k$ of the possible indices $i$ in $\{1,...,n\}$ then $y = 1$, where $k$ and $n$ are parameters, $x$ is a binary variable vector with $n$ elements, $y$ is a binary variable.

I already tried to build constraints, but it is difficult to me to find the one that ensures the feasibility / infeasibility of certain combinations.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

$$
\sum_{i=1}^n x_i \leq k-1 + (n-k+1)y
$$

Comment: +1. A simple way to derive this is to use the contrapositive $y=0\implies \sum_i x_i \le k-1$ and impose the big-M constraint $\sum_i x_i-(k-1)\le My$, where $M$ is an upper bound on the LHS when $y=1$.

Comment: @RobPratt I could not understand why: k-1 and n-k+1 as big-M??would be grateful for an answer

Comment: @I.A I added an answer just now.

Answer (score 6):

By request, here's an explicit derivation.  The desired logical implication is $$\sum_{i=1}^n x_i \ge k \implies y = 1.$$
Its contrapositive is
$$y \not= 1 \implies \sum_{i=1}^n x_i < k,$$
equivalently (because $y$ is binary and $\sum_i x_i$ is an integer),
$$y = 0 \implies \sum_{i=1}^n x_i \le k - 1.$$
This logical implication can be enforced via big-M constraint
$$\sum_{i=1}^n x_i - (k - 1) \le M y.$$
If $y=0$, then $\sum_{i=1}^n x_i - (k - 1) \le 0$, as desired.
If $y=1$, then $\sum_{i=1}^n x_i - (k - 1) \le M$, and we want to choose the smallest $M$ that makes the constraint redundant, so take $M$ to be an upper bound on the left-hand side:
$$M = \sum_{i=1}^n 1 - (k - 1) = n - k + 1.$$
The desired constraint is thus
$$\sum_{i=1}^n x_i - (k - 1) \le (n - k + 1) y,$$
equivalently,
$$\sum_{i=1}^n x_i \le k - 1 + (n - k + 1) y.$$