# Conditional constraint for binary variables

Tags: linear-programming, modeling, binary-variable, logical-constraints

I would appreciate any help to solve the following task:

If $y=1$ then $x_i=1$ for at least $k$ of the possible indices $i\in\{1,\cdots,n\}$ where $k$ and $n$ are parameters, $x$ is a binary variable vector with $n$ elements, and $y$ is a binary variable.

Comment: This is very similar to your last [post](https://or.stackexchange.com/questions/9365/binary-variable-constraint). Can you work it out with the answer provided there ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want to enforce $y=1 \implies \sum_i x_i \ge k$.  You can do so by imposing linear big-M constraint
$$k - \sum_i x_i \le (k - 0) (1 - y),$$
which simplifies to
$$\sum_i x_i \ge k y.$$